# RHCSA exam local repo subscription manager error,

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, redhat, archlinux, redhat-containers

I took the RHCSA certification exam and Question 2 required me to create a local repo. I executed the command "yum config-manager --add-repo / path / to / AppStream", but when I executed the commands "yum clean all" and "yum install httpd", I was required to "subscription manager regisrty". I informed the supervisor about this. But he said that I was wrong. I told them that they had to solve it. And I did not move on to the next task in the exam. It took me a lot of time.
I wrote to the person who sent the exam results. they also just send me exam results. Where can I apply for this?

Comment: Is this a permissions issue? Why do you expect us to solve this if your certification folks could not? If not, please [edit] your question and include all the steps you ran and what the exact output was; we need a [mcve]. Don't paraphrase errors, google them instead.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use that command in RHCSA exam.You have to add repo manually.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a repo in /etc/yum.repos.d/, These are the steps to create a local repo.

```
vim /etc/yum.repos.d/     #create a new file here. 
                          #yum config looks in this folder when searching for repositories              
                          #configure file as seen below with the given repo urls and name. 

[AppStream]                                        #this is just a tag name
name=AppStream                                     #name of repo
baseurl=https://whatever.xyz.redhat.com/AppStream  #url of repo you are given
gpgcheck=0                                         #this tells yum to not check gpgkeys for repo
enable=1                                           #this enables the local repo

yum clean all
```

This should work to have yum recognize the repos you want to connect to and install from. you may need to also log into the repo using

```
subscription-manager register       #hit enter to add username and password.
```

Hopes this helps.